# What variables are available in the "Next Best Action" Flow

Tags: einstein-recommendations

I've been looking into Einstein Recommendations for a client and managed to get everything setup.

The only issue I am having is the Accept/Reject Flow.

The ***only*** variable input I can find documentation for is *isRecommendationAccepted*, which is found here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nba_launch_flow_accepts_rejects.htm&type=5.

I worked out I can use `{!recordId}` to get the Id of the record that the button was clicked on, but I need to know what was recommended so I can create the Recommendation Response record correctly.

Also off the back of the Acceptance, I want to be able to actually create Records for the client.

**Small Update**

I also worked out we can use `{!id}` to get the Id of the record that was recommended, but still unable to see what Recommendation was actually selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out what the issue is... there is no issue and the documentation is rubbish!

When a User clicks on either button to accept or reject the recommendation, it immediately does the accept/reject piece, the Flow is just an additional piece that runs after, if you want it to...

Answer (score 0):

You may try {!recommendationId}
But not sure, the only mention I found is https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_nba_resources.htm